# Growing strands with particles

Tags: particles

Is something like this possible in Blender ?

[image: Growing strands]

I need random movement of particles, which leaves static strands behind.

Comment: This is possible using hair particles (the trail effect could be done in post processing by fading frames out  over time).

Comment: I need real strands, no any echos or duplicate in postproduction, this is exactly what I need: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVqUaaozE5Y]

Comment: Do you think [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtKcPFeEJcg) can be yet another acceptable solution? And I wonder whether you mean to have static strands for dynamic and random particles to follow?

Comment: Use hair particle with Hair Dyamics On. Add up force field, like wind and turbulance ( you may need to add up 2 or 3 for the effect) , Keep the hair particle length more then 10.
Setup the material with strand options on. Add up a blend texture, which will effect the alpha and a color ramp to give multi colors.

Comment: @Cenda Oh. I mis-understood what you wanted..

Comment: And here is a blend file with the advice given above.http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using trails and lines in BI. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like best solution for me :) thanks .. btw, is there any option for controling grow by curve / path ?

Comment: I thought you needed particles. For growth along curves Ivy gen addon is probably a good fit for you. http://bioblog3d.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/iga-is-ready/

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *Halo* material and *Trail Particles* to do this.

[image: Animated gif]

1. Use a *turbulence* force field to create the random motion. (You can also use the *Brownian* value in *Particles > Physics*, but I liked the motion created by the turbulence force-field better)

   [image]
2. Set the *Trail count* up. 700 may be a bit much if you have a lot of particles, and unnecessary if your particles don't move very fast.

   [image]
3. Use a *Halo* material for the particles:

   [image]