# Particle trails in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Is there a way to render trails behind particles in cycles?

I tried using hair particles with *Use force field weights for growing* enabled and a turbulence force-field, however the trails become unstable after a point:

[image]

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd leave a better reply, but it's so late right now. In the meantime, I think I remember this video showed how to do that:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6SZp77VNqM

Comment: @ThomBlairIII It looks like that tutorial is for BI.. Also it doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for. I want to make something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7606/599), but in cycles.

Comment: Isn't the instability caused by the turbulance force field? It is Turbulance after all...

Comment: @someonewithpc AFAIK it shouldn't. There are no dynamics and the field is not animated.. The hair strands should just grow in the pattern of the turbulence. It does at first, but then it gets unstable. Here's a .blend if you want to play around with it.. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30752

Comment: Can't at the moment,  I'm on my tablet

Answer (score 13):

You cannot do this with blender/cycles particles itself but you can use [BTrace addon](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/btrace/) to create animated curves from traced particles:

[image]

The addon is still under development but it works very nicely.