# How to make anime/toon like procedural wind texture, blender 2.9 eevee

Tags: animation, texturing, eevee-render-engine

How to make procedural wind texture in an anime/toon style. Which can be put mainly on planes.

Like these, but the creators didn't say how they did it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117090/particles-with-motion-trails and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips/94976#94976 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/how-do-i-achieve-a-particle-trail-effect and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a curve, give it extrusion in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Geometry > Extrude*, then give it a material that is a mix between a *Transparent* and an *Emission* node with a *Texture > Musgrave Texture* as factor (in Eevee don't forget to choose *Alpha Blend* in the material settings). In the *Mapping* node, stretch the texture on one axis:

[image]

You can blur the borders with a second *ColorRamp*:

[image]

Then use the *Location* values to move the streaks:

[image]

As for the ring around the ball, create it with a *Geomtery > Bevel > Object* instead of an *Extrude*, and choose a oval or a rectangle as *Object*. And for the material, from what I see in your animation, enable both the *Show Backface* and the *Backface Culling* options in the material settings to get the right transparency:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank god, you have no idea how long I've been looking for this, but I got one more question, how do you do the wind around the ball/object. I repeated the part with the edges, but it doesn't look as good.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "around the ball"? it looks like he put a bezier curve circle, is it what you mean?

Comment: Yea, that's the one. I know it's a 3d objects and not flat like the curved ones.

Comment: oh yes I think I know how you can do it, i'm going to edit

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the hassle. I'm still new to blender.

Comment: I've tried something for the ring, it's not exactly what he did, it's close

Comment: It's fine, I'll start experimenting with it but again thank you.

Comment: Ok I've changed the material settings; actually you should better enable both the Show Backface and the Backface Culling options  ;)