# Increase Motion Blur Effect 2.81

Tags: blur, motion-blur

I'm a first time blender user who would like the increase the motion blur effect for my scene. Essentially, my goal is to reproduce [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117090/particles-with-motion-trails); I have followed that user's instructions(I have yet to overlay the images though).

I would like to increase the blur trail of my molecule and **emphasize the rotation**. I'm open to a different approach! Thanks!

[image]

This is my shutter curve:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exaggerate motion blur use a larger value for the shutter. The slider is limited to 1, but  click on the shutter value and manually type a larger number.

[image]

Also, don't use rolling shutter, set it to none.

Comment: Solved! Thank you!