# How to make a lightning trail like The Flash?

Tags: particles

I want to make a lightning trail from The Flash where it automatically curves and moves with the character without setting up a bezier-curve

For Example:

https://youtu.be/HDiN4uMDG4Y

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFPFo.jpg

Comment: Related: [Particle trails in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7744/particle-trails-in-cycles), [How to add trailing light effect to finger tips?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips) and [How to create Motion Trail in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24270/31447)

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)