# How can i download/install the Motion Trail-addon (svn-download)?

Tags: add-on

I tried to download it on [this](https://developer.blender.org/T26374) page, but after clicking on the link next to *SVN Download* i was redirected to another page with 3 other links. After clicking them i was redirected to a new page with a whole bunch of new links. So i realized that i needed to install SVN (Subversion) for my Mac, but after i've done it successfully, i still don't know what to do.

How can i install this addon using Subversion or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Try downloading it from their [website](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/motion_trail#TOC-Download) instead. It seems blender's switch to git may have messed up that link slightly

Comment: @gandalf3 It's the same thing on the website.

Comment: If you click on the links for the files a new page opens, on the right there is an option to download  http://i.stack.imgur.com/EE90W.png

Comment: to install an addon see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon

Comment: Thank you. I was able to download and install it (a new tool appeared on the left screen. But somehow Blender crashes when i click on the 'enable motion trail'-button. Was it right to install all 3 files simultaneously?

Comment: that perticular addon has been buggy since 2.73... you might want to use an earlier version of blender...

Comment: for alternative ways to create motion trails see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7579/growing-strands-with-particles/7606#7606 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While blender has moved it's revision control to git nearly two years ago, you can still find links to the old svn repository, even on blender's own wiki.

While blender's source code is split into four repositories and there are a few other repositories for related projects the one that most users would be interested in is the Add-ons Contrib which can now be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/), where you can also find the git command to download the entire repo. The contrib repo is a collection of semi-official addons that haven't been accepted into the official releases of blender. The old links that you find starting with `projects.blender.org` or `svn.blender.org` that have `/contrib/` in the path can now be found at `developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC`

Now specifically for the addon you mention, the multiple links on the page are different versions of the same addon submitted during it's review process, the addon is contained in one file, the issue you have may be from different versions conflicting or an older version loading first and preventing the new one loading. Remove the older files so that only one new version is installed.

Near the top of an addon script you will find `bl_info = {` followed by a list of values, the one you are interested in is "version" -

```
bl_info = {
    ...
    "version": (3, 1, 2),
    ...
```

only keep the one with the highest version.